# Save image in video clip editor?

Tags: image, video

I have a video in the video clip editor,and I want to save the current frame as a photo om my computer,is there is any fast way to save an image directly from the video clip editor?

Comment: But this is just a screen capture not saving a frame from the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Crl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> is the shortcut to save images from any screen.

Alternatively, in the preview window you can press the camera button to render the active viewport. The rendered image will then be available in the UV/Image viewer, where you can then click View->Save As Image (or <kbd>Crl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>)